# What does it take to send a probe into a primordial black hole near the Oort cloud?

Tags: probe, interstellar-travel, uncrewed-spaceflight, black-hole

Since Sept 2019 there's been some speculation<sup>1</sup> whether the hypothetical planet far beyond the Kuiper belt is actually a primordial black hole. It would be the closest black hole to the Earth (500 au from the Sun on average) and we might send a probe there.

I've already discussed the speed needed to enter the black hole on astronomy.SE and a user (don't remember who anymore) concluded that the probe must enter at close-to-light-speed in order to not get spaghettified and torn apart. And since the black hole would have a diameter of about 2 inches (5 cm) the probe must be very small of course, with the camera on its peak, so that it enters the black hole camera-first. The probe probably would consist only of a camera.

Is it realistically possible to achieve a speed of 0.95 c for a probe (perhaps Breakthrough Starshot with a swing-by on a star) and what else would it take to make the probe safely fly into the black hole? And might it be risky because a man-made probe might exit the black hole in another location and/or time?

Perhaps I should tell you that it doesn't matter whether the speculation is true. The question is what it takes to enter it, so just *assume* there *is* a primordial black hole.

<sup>1</sup>Gizomodo's [What If Planet Nine Is a Bowling Ball-Size Black Hole?](https://gizmodo.com/what-if-planet-nine-is-a-bowling-ball-size-black-hole-1838527880) links to the arXiv preprint [What if Planet 9 is a Primordial Black Hole?](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.11090)

Comment: "Safely" and "black hole" can't be used in the same sentence.

Comment: I love the image of the "Exact scale (1:1) illustration of a 5M⊕ PBH" :-)

Comment: @uhoh But I think that depends on how much zoom you use in your browser.

Comment: For Gizmodo that's certainly true, but for the PDF in the arXiv paper I think those files contain real dimensions in their embedded images. I'm no expert on it, but I think if we printed out the PDFs anywhere in the world with different paper standards 8.5x11 vs A4 we'd get almost (if not exactly) the same size.

Comment: It doesn't matter how fast your probe goes. It can't outrace the event horizon's gravitational time dilation, gravitational redshift, and the fact that it's an event horizon..No information from any part of the probe that crosses the event horizon in its own reference frame gets back to any reference frame that isn't also crossing the event horizon.

Comment: @notovny It might exit through a white hole in the vicinity of the Earth and hopefully in the present. Your ultimate proof for an Einstein Rosen Bridge.

Comment: You're going to accelerate a tiny probe to 0.95c then hit a 5 cm target with it?

Comment: @DanPichelman That's certainly feasible for experts IF you could accelerate to 0.95 c, but as Philipp said, it would be unrealistic to accelerate to that speed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the probe must be very small of course, with the camera on its peak, so that it enters the black hole camera-first. The probe probably would consist only of a camera.

What would you hope to accomplish by that? Information can not escape the event horizon of a black hole. That's why they are black. If you could "dip" a camera behind the event horizon (which you can't, because it won't be a functional camera at that point), the image it records could not pass back outside. The image signal would have to travel faster than the speed of light in order to escape the event horizon, which is impossible according to our current understanding of physics.

> Is it realistically possible to achieve a speed of 0.95 c for a probe (perhaps Breakthrough Starshot with a swing-by on a star)

No, not with present technology and likely not with foreseeable future technology either. The fastest speed for a space probe I could find is [NASA's Juno probe with 692,000 km/h](https://www.space.com/41447-parker-solar-probe-fastest-spacecraft-ever.html). That's 0.00064c. And the problem with relativistic speeds is that the closer you get to the speed of light, the more energy you need to accelerate further.

There is also the question what you would want to accomplish by doing that. You will only get a very, very short time window in which the probe could collect any data. In order to maximize scientific value you would want the probe to observe the object for a longer time. Even if you would want to observe the probe from the outside while it gets swallowed by a black hole, you would want that to happen slowly so you can collect more data.

> and what else would it take to make the probe safely fly into the black hole?

You can not "safely" fly into a black hole. You might get some interesting data by flying a probe *near* a black hole. But you can't get it too close to a black hole, because [the gravitational shear forces will tear it apart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghettification).

> And might it be risky because a man-made probe might exit the black hole in another location and/or time?

1. There is no scientific reason to believe that black holes can do that. That's something science fiction authors made up. The current consensus among astrophysicists is that anything that falls into a black hole becomes a part of it and is irretrieveable lost. Any information about what it once was is lost. [It just contributes to the hole's mass, electric charge and momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-hair_theorem).
2. Even if the scientists thought wrong and the science fiction authors guessed right, the gravitational forces would crush the probe into worthless bits of scrap metal long before it touches the event horizon.

Comment: White holes are one theory. If you enter a black hole and reach where "singularity" is presumed, you can in fact exit the black hole in a white hole on the other side. There's a report of a pilot (don't remember his name) who above the Bermuda triangle flew through an Einstein Rosen Bridge which teleported him to his goal Miami. It looked like a tunnel within a strange cloud. The extreme magnetism there might explain the opening of such bridge.

Comment: I found out the pilot's name: Bruce Gernon Jr.. He reports to have flown through a ~1 mile tunnel where he was weightless and the instruments of his airplane failed until he exited the Einstein Rosen Bridge.

Comment: @user30007 There is so much about that story which makes no scientific sense whatsoever that I can not explain it within just 600 characters. You might want to post that story on https://skeptics.stackexchange.com and let them point out all the flaws in that story.

Comment: @user30007 [This video of astrophysicist and science educator Neil deGrasse Tyson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9BRDCxNEuyg) might help you to better understand how such "reports" should be approached from a scientific perspective. He is talking about UFOs here, but it applies just the same to this claim "I flew through an Einstein-Rosen Bridge".

Comment: Mr Gernon explains his occurence with electronic fog which may be due to the extreme electromagnetism in that area (as well as other areas on Earth). The poor pilots that vanished above the triangle obviously flew to other planets and/or stars so they couldn't return to tell. Mr Gernon was actually very lucky that the bridge took him to a location on Earth and close to his goal.

Comment: @user30007 "*Obviously* flew to other planets"? Uhmm.... no, there is nothing obvious about that. You really should stop believing everything you read on paranormal mystery websites or see on History Channel.

Comment: This exchange has illuminated many questions I have pondered about recent events on space stack exchange.

Comment: @Philipp I also recommend you "Missing in Alaska" on Discovery Channel. One episode is concerning Einstein Rosen Bridges. Seemingly Alaska is another magnetic hot spot, as you might conclude from other episodes too. Really strange things happen in Alaska.

Comment: @user30007 You do know that planes fly over the Bermuda Triangle thousands of times per year, right?

Comment: @StarMan They better shouldn't be allowed to fly over the parts where pilots vanished, nor should they be allowed to fly over the Alaska triangle explained in the above-mentioned documentary nor any other such area of extreme electromagnetism. Allowing it is negligently endangering pilot's and passenger's lives.

Comment: @user30007 Ummm..no. They pretty much fly all over the Bermuda triangle. Pilots don't actively avoid it.

Comment: @StarMan If they did I wouldn't have made the comment above but they should avoid these dangerous areas. Laws must be passed to prohibit pilots from flying airliners over them despite Gernon's occurence happening at 11,000 ft or so.